# How can I make the package config merge it's non-existing keys into the app config file in laravel 7.x?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing some packages that make my app more modular and allow the user to enable/disable them on the fly, or install additional packages when needed.

Some of these packages will require the user to configure certain properties (such as api-keys), for this reason I'd like the packages to write their config keys & values to the `<app-root>/config/packages.php` file (if the keys don't exist yet).

From what I understand from the laravel documentation (albeit a bit vague) I can use either:

```
$this->mergeConfigFrom(__DIR__.'/config/config.php', 'packages');
```

or

```
$this->publishes([
    __DIR__.'/config/config.php' => config_path('packages.php')
]);
```

in the `register()` method of my package `ServiceProvider` class.

Additionally I also added an `echo "called";` to the `register()` method so I can check if the code is actually executed.

Next I run `compose dump-autoload`, I see `called` in the log output, but when I check the `<app-root>/config/packages.php` file it still has the empty array.

Using `php artisan config:clear` and then running `compose dump-autoload` once more doesn't make a difference either.

How can I make the package config merge it's non-existing keys into the `<app-root>/config/packages.php` file?

This is an example of my package config file:

```
<?php

return [
    'shoutzor' => [
        'acoustid' => [
            'apikey'  => env('SHOUTZOR_ACOUSTID_APIKEY', '')
        ]
    ]
];
```

and my `<app-root>/config/packages.php` file contains:

```
<?php

return [];
```

Comment: I believe you misunderstand `mergeConfigFrom`. This is not to merge non-package published configs with your package config. `mergeConfigFrom` allows you to merge your own package configuration file with the application's published copy. That will allow your users to define only the options they actually want to override in the published copy of the configuration.

Comment: Ah, yes that would appear to be the case. I found it quite difficult to understand the documentation when it came to the difference between `publishes` and `mergeConfigFrom`.

Comment: Combining package and removing them later will give you polluted configs if you merge them. I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: Fair point. Though in my app I don't expect users to change these packages a lot. But I'll see if there's a better approach to this.

Comment: Approach building packages as if you write them for a huge angry open-source community ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You (or the user) need to run the command `php artisan vendor:publish` before the package's configuration file will be published (copied in the `config` folder, or the folder specified)

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/packages#resources)

> Now, when users of your package execute Laravel's *`vendor:publish`* command, your file will be copied to the specified publish location.

If you want to publish a specific package vendor files, you will just need to pass the package service provider as option to the command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Your\Package\ServiceProvider"
```

*Important*
If the files to publish already exist in the destination folder, you will need to run the command with the `--force` option:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --force
```

Comment: Gave that a try, it shows up in the list and when I select it, it says "Publishing complete.". Yet the `<app-root>/config/packages.php` file is still an empty array. EDIT: I added an example of my config to the question

Comment: Turns out that the `$this->publishes()` command doesn't add missing keys if the config file already exists. This would mean I'd have separate config files for every package. Is there no way of combining these? (ie: merge missing keys)

Comment: Run the command with `--force` option to overwrite the config file if it already exists

Comment: Force replaces the custom values added by the user. So there is no way of merging them? If not, that's an answer too ;) at least I'm not stuck on nothing happening anymore.

Comment: If you wanna merge, Use `$this->mergeConfigFrom()` instead